# how to get [Time][2013].[All].[5]

Tags: mdx

I need to insert a condition into the where to display the 5th day of all the months of the year 2013

[Time][2013].[All].[5]

The All keyword doesn't work.
Anyone can help me? Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Can you use the underlying fields of the hierarchy to achieve your goal?  It looks like your hierarchy is made of [Time].[Year], [Time].[Month], and [Time].[Day of Month].  You could have a where clause that is `([Time].[Year].[2013], [Time].[Day of Month].[5])`

You should be able to reference items in the hierarchy without denoting the entire path from the top level down.  If you must use the hierarchy try something like this:

`Exists({DESCENDANTS([Time].[Hierarchy].[Year].[2013], [Time].[Hierarchy].[Day of Month])},[Time].[Hierarchy].[Day of Month].[5])`

Comment: Thanks but if i use ([Time].[Year].[2013], [Time].[Day of Month].[5]) i see all the rows with year 2013 and all the rows with day 5. I need cond1 and cond2 not cond1 or cond2.

Comment: Using ([Time].[Year].[2013], [Time].[Day of Month].[5]) in the where clause would create an AND situation, not OR. Where are you putting that clause? See MSDN for examples: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms146047.aspx  I would have to see your entire query to understand why you are getting that result.